# How to handle unavailable services using service remoting

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

I'm using [service remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-remoting) to connect service A with service B. While deploying, I've noticed that it is possible for service A to call a method in service B while service B is still starting up. In which case `AddStringToDictionary` throws a `NullReferenceException` because `RunAsync` has not been called yet.

```
public interface IServiceB : IService
{
    Task AddStringToDictionary(string key, string value);
}

internal sealed class ServiceB : StatefulService, IServiceB
{
    private IReliableDictionary<string, string> myDictionary;

    public ServiceB(StatefulServiceContext context)
        : base(context)
    { 
        // StateMananger is null here.
    }

    public async Task AddStringToDictionary(string key, string value) 
    {
        using (var tx = StateManager.CreateTransaction())
        {
            // myDictionary is null if this is called before RunAsync.
            await this.myDictionary.SetAsync(tx, key, value);
            await tx.CommitAsync();
        }
    }

    protected override async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
    {
        this.myDictionary = await this.StateManager.GetOrAddAsync<IReliableDictionary<string, string>>("myDictionary");
    }
}
```

I know that I can use the `StateManager.GetOrAddAsync` method in `AddStringToDictionary`, but I might want to initialize some more fields. The constructor is not useful either because the `StateManager` doesn't exist there yet. My current solution is to add a field:

```
private bool serviceAvailable = false;
```

I'm setting this field to `true` at the end of `RunAsync`. Every public method then calls `ThrowIfServiceUnavailable()`.

```
private void ThrowIfServiceUnavailable()
{
    if (!serviceAvailable)
    {
        throw new ServiceUnavailableException();
    }
}

public async Task AddStringToDictionary(string key, string value) 
{
    ThrowIfServiceUnavailable();
    ...
}
```

Currently I have to handle the `ServiceUnavailableException` every time I call a method with remoting. My question is: are there any better ways to handle this situation or is this a good solution? And is it possible to add my custom exception to the `ServiceProxy`'s transient exceptions to retry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's](https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.PubSubActors/blob/master/ServiceFabric.PubSubActors/BrokerServiceBase.cs) an implementation that blocks calls while the service is being initialized. It uses `ManualResetEventSlim` to block.
And it uses `SemaphoreSlim` to enforce single threaded access to an async operation.

All Service operations call `await WaitForInitializeAsync(CancellationToken.None);`
And the implementation of this method is:

```
private async Task WaitForInitializeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (_initializer.IsSet) return;
    await Task.Run(() => InitializeAsync(cancellationToken), cancellationToken);
   _initializer.Wait(cancellationToken);
}
```

The implementation of InitializeAsync:

```
private async Task InitializeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
   if (_initializer.IsSet) return;
   try
   {
      _semaphore.Wait(cancellationToken);
      if (_initializer.IsSet) return;
      [initializer logic here]
```